# Additionals rpm to red hat iso with a kickstart file

Tags: linux, redhat, iso

I spent a very long time searching for an answer in internet but I
   found nothing. I want to add custom rpm to a red hat workstation iso
   dvd. I do the following things:

- mount a red hat iso (`mount -t iso9660
  rhel-workstation-6.4-i386-dvd.iso /mnt/iso`)
- copy all dvd files to a directory including hidden .discinfo and .treeinfo files :
  `cp -R /mnt/iso/* /tmp/isofiles;

  cp/mnt/iso/.discinfo /tmp/isofiles;

  cp /mnt/iso/.treeinfo /tmp/isofiles`
- then I add additionals rpm to the `/tmp/isofiles/Packages` directory which is a part of the dvd tree
- then I rebuild the repo in `/tmp/isofiles` with the command createrepo (`createrepo --update -g comps.xml` .)
- at last I rebuild the iso with `mkisofs` and burn it to a dvd.   Note that I also have a kickstart file to automate the installation.
  The problem is that during the rpm installation step the dvd is
  ejected and I have a message that ask me to insert the Red Hat Linux
  Entreprise disc 1. I don't understand why. This only appears if I
  modified the repository. Can you help me please ?

Answer (score 0):

Is the RedHat version of your system (where your ran **createrepo** command) same as the version of redhat.iso that you are modifying?

Not sure if its same, but similar issue has been answered [here](http://www.redhat.com/archives/kickstart-list/2011-March/msg00007.html)

Comment: Yes I ran the createrepo command in a Red Hat Workstation 6.4. It's the same then the iso.
I yet saw the link below but it did not help me.

Answer (score 0):

This is the syntax i have used for RHEL 6, and it works just fine I just add my rpms to the default Server folder

```
#for a new Boot disk, delete the contents of ~/repodata , this clears out he old rpm lists
#copy cda5429be6f36ce1...-comps-rhel6-Server.xml repodata/comps-rhel6-Server.xml from Official RHEL iso
#run the command below, will create all the needed files
discinfo=`head -1 .discinfo
createrepo -u "media://$discinfo" -g $compdata .
```